# Easiest validation regular expression not matching space at beginning or end

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to find the easiest validation regular expression (PCRE) for use in method preg_match() in PHP. I want to keep it as easy as possible and avoid repetition if possible.

My matching criteria in words is:

- Allow one or more characters (this implies string should be 1 characters and up in total) from the following list:

  ```
  a-zA-Z0-9 +&-
  ```
- Do not allow space in beginning or end

My regular expression knowledge might be lacking but what I come up with without the second space criterion is:

```
    /^[a-zA-Z0-9 +&-]+$/
```

To not match space I'm thinking about something like

```
    /^[^ ]+[a-zA-Z0-9 +&-]+[^ ]+$/
```

but this actual piece would need 3+ characters.

If I do

```
    /^[^ ]*[a-zA-Z0-9 +&-]+[^ ]*$/
```

it will not work at all times either, I suppose it has to do with the "greediness" of the middle part, but I've really tried to research how to get it right without succeeding.

Thankful for any kind of advice or pointer in the right direction!

Comment: You know what [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) does, right?

Comment: `[^ ]` could be replaced with `\S`, which is the general "not whitespace"

Comment: @CodeCaster: Hehe, yes, I very much understand what trim() does. This is a validation regular expression before passing it on to a sub-system, if it doesn't match a certain pattern the string should be rejected so I cannot simply trim() it
MarcB: I know, but space is the only whitespace character I can allow in the string so it does unfortunately not help me as I see it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to wrap both `[^ ]` conditions into assertions. Lefthand `(?=)` and `(?<=)` at the end.

```
 /^(?=[^ ])[a-zA-Z0-9 +&-]+(?<=\S)$/
```

I think it's sufficient if you test just for one non-space character on each end. Then it's already ensured the content begins with a letter or another allowed character.

See http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html for a nice explanation.

Comment: Actually this does not meet the requirements of his validation. [^ ] can match any character that is not a space, including /\?_= which he does not want.

Comment: Thanks mario! As I started reading about assertions I came up with the following regular expression which seem to be the solution:
^(?=[^ ])[a-zA-Z0-9 +&-]+(?<=[^ ])$
@Thorbear: Correct me if I'm wrong, but all I want to make sure is that string does not start or end with a space and then contains one or more of the characters in the character list - and as I understand my regex above takes care of that? I mean, even if the positive assertion match an introductory /\? _ or whatever, it still wouldn't be allowed through the list of characters coming next. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Thorbear: He only said spaces. But of course any other number of exceptions can be added to the `[^ ]` negated character class. Even if that initially matches any weird characters `?_ö:@` - the following character class would not allow them. The magic of the assertions is that they work in conjunction with the actual matching / capturing sections.

Comment: @mario It seems you are correct. I was too focused on the fact that [^ ] matches any non-space character to remember how it works within a lookahead. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Your main character class includes a space character, so even though you explicitly exclude spaces with the `[^ ]*` portion, you still ALLOW spaces with your main `[a-z...]`, so you've effectly negated the entire purpose of the regex.

basically, you've put up a no parking sign that says "no parking anytime. parking allowed 9-5".

---

followup: What you want are negative assertions:

```
/^(?<!\s)[a-z.....](?>!\s)$/
```

The first one is a negative (`!`) look-behind (`<`) assertion that says "do not allow a whitespace (`\s`) before whatever follows (`[a-z...]`). The other one is the same, but is a negative look-ahead (`>`).

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but not how to express what I want, i.e. allow spaces as long as they are not in the beginning of the string (with preference to a minimum of repetition). I could of course split this into two regular expressions / validations, but I just it in a configuration file and that would only complicate things.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't want to just be given a pattern so I'll try to give some pointers instead.

You want to match a string that begins with any character from the list `[a-zA-Z0-9+&-]`, you want it to be followed by any character from that same list or a space, for an unlimited length.

To make the pattern as short as possible, you can remember that  `*`  matches from 0 to unlimited times, which means that whatever you put in front of it, does not actually have to appear there at all; the pattern `(ab*)+`  can match `ab` or `abab` or `aaa` but never `ba`

Answer (score 0):

I would put focus on what is wanted.

`^(?i)[a-z0-9+&-][a-z0-9 +&-]*(?<=[a-z0-9+&-])$`

Comment: It's probably a working suggestion, but my aim was to minimize repetition and the best solution I found was ^(?=[^ ])[a-zA-Z0-9 +&-]+(?<=[^ ])$ to match all my requirements. Thanks for your involvement though sln!